# Usando "If" dentro de triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, trigger

Tengo creado un trigger para que recoja un valor introducido, lo relacione con otra table y lo cambie. Ese valor puede ser bastante peculiar, por lo que lo busco en dos campos y además concatenándolo:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "INTER_AGENTE" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON intercambios
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT ag_nombre INTO :NEW.int_vendedor 
FROM agentes 
WHERE ag_denominacion like concat(:NEW.int_vendedor,'%') 
      or :NEW.int_vendedor like concat(ag_nombre, '%');
```

Esto funciona correctamente en todos los casos salvo en uno, que obtengo error ya que encuentra coincidencias en dos registros, en campos diferentes.

Encuentra un valor que se parece en ag_denominacion en ag_nombre = "CASO1", pero también encuentra un valor que se le parece en ag_nombre y entonces introduciría ag_nombre ="CASO2".

Se me ocurre dar preferencias, es decir, si encuentra una coincidencia con ag_denominacion pues que se quede con esa. Si no encuentra nada, que busque en ag_nombre.

¿Cómo lo véis?¿Es posible?

Comment: Agregué la etiqueta Oracle y PL/SQL, porque por el código que pusistes (sobre todo el dos puntos delante de `:NEW`) es obvio que esa es la base de datos que usas.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con `top 1`
cambiando esto:

```
SELECT ag_nombre INTO :NEW.int_vendedor
```

por esto:

```
SELECT top 1 ag_nombre INTO :NEW.int_vendedor
```

Si no, se me ocurre también de la siguiente manera:

```
if(exists(SELECT top 1 ag_nombre FROM agentes WHERE ag_denominacion like concat(:NEW.int_vendedor,'%'))) 
    begin       
        SELECT ag_nombre INTO :NEW.int_vendedor 
        FROM agentes 
        WHERE ag_denominacion like concat(:NEW.int_vendedor,'%');
    end
else
    begin
        SELECT ag_nombre INTO :NEW.int_vendedor 
        FROM agentes 
        WHERE :NEW.int_vendedor like concat(ag_nombre, '%');
    end
```

Tendrías que validarlo no estoy segura, pero así va la idea.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque pudieras hacerlo con un `IF`, esto implicaría consultar la tabla `agentes` por lo menos 2 veces (o hasta 3 dependiendo de cómo lo haces).

Siendo que se trata de un trigger que dispara para cada registro insertado o modificado de la tabla `intercambios`, lo mejor sería evitar consultar la tabla `agentes` varias veces.

Por eso, para lograr lo que pides, pero sin empeorar el rendimiento, sugiero que modifiques la consulta usando una claúsula `ORDER BY` para devolver en prioridad los registros que coinciden con `ag_denominacion` y luego los que coinciden con `ag_nombre`. Luego puedes usar `rownum` para limitar el resultado al primer registro:

```
SELECT ag_nombre INTO :NEW.int_vendedor
  FROM (SELECT ag_nombre
          FROM agentes
         WHERE ag_denominacion LIKE CONCAT(:NEW.int_vendedor,'%')
            OR :NEW.int_vendedor LIKE CONCAT(ag_nombre, '%')
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN ag_denominacion LIKE CONCAT(:NEW.int_vendedor,'%')
                       THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```